# Adding data by row into an empty matrix and handling missing data

Tags: r, matrix

I have an empty matrix with a certain number of columns that I'm trying to fill row-by-row with output vectors of a for-loop. However, some of the output are not the same length as the number of columns as my matrix, and just want to fill up those "empty spaces" with NAs.

For example:

```
matrix.names <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "y1", "y2", "y3", "y4", "z1", "z2", "z3", "z4")
my.matrix <- matrix(ncol = length(matrix.names))
colnames(my.matrix) <- matrix.names
```

This would be the output from one iteration:

```
x <- c(1,2)
y <- c(4,2,1,5)
z <- c(1)
```

Where I would want it in the matrix like this:

```
      x1 x2  x3 x4 y1 y2 y3 y4 z1 z2 z3 z4
[1,]   1  2  NA NA  4  2  1  5  1 NA NA NA
```

The output from the next iteration would be, for example:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1)
y <- c(0,4)
z <- c(4,1,3)
```

And added as a new row in the matrix:

```
      x1 x2 x3 x4 y1 y2 y3 y4 z1 z2 z3 z4
[1,]   1  2 NA NA  4  2  1  5  1 NA NA NA
[2,]   1  1  1  1  0  4 NA NA  4  1  3 NA
```

It's not really a concern if I have a 0, it's just where there is no data. Also, the data is saved in such a way that whatever is there is listed in the row first, followed by NAs in empty slots. In other words, I'm not worried if an NA may pop up first.

Also, is such a thing better handled in data frames rather than matrices?

Comment: Thank you @joel.wilson for the edits

Comment: I posted a solution below, Please check if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the efficient answer : just a try

`logic` : extending the length to 4.(exception could be if already x/y/z is laready of length4) Therefore while `rbind`ing I only extract the first 4 elements .

```
x[length(x)+1:4] <- NA  
y[length(y)+1:4] <- NA
z[length(z)+1:4] <- NA


my.matrix <- rbind(my.matrix,c(x[1:4],y[1:4],z[1:4]))
```

Note : the exception I mentioned above is like below :

```
> x <- c(1,1,1,1)
> x
[1] 1 1 1 1
> x[length(x)+1:4] <- NA
> x
[1]  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA  # therefore I extract only the first four
```

Comment: What will the +1:4 do?

Comment: so I extend the current length to make it of length 4 bcoz we want each vector `x/y/z` to be length 4 right

Comment: Right, got it! I'll give it a try

Comment: I have tried it on my large dataset and it worked! Thanks very much!

Comment: How do I accept the answer? I just know I can upvote, but not sure how to accept it. Sorry I'm new!

Comment: below the voting option you might find a tick symbol

Comment: Booyah, there we go! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option to do this programmatically

```
d1 <- stack(mget(c("x", "y", "z")))[2:1]
nm <- with(d1, paste0(ind, ave(seq_along(ind),ind, FUN = seq_along)))
my.matrix[,match(nm,colnames(my.matrix), nomatch = 0)] <- d1$values
my.matrix
#     x1 x2 x3 x4 y1 y2 y3 y4 z1 z2 z3 z4
#[1,]  1  2 NA NA  4  2  1  5  1 NA NA NA
```

---

Or another option is `stri_list2matrix` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
m1 <- as.numeric(stri_list2matrix(list(x,y, z)))
```

Change the 'x', 'y', 'z' values

```
m2 <- as.numeric(stri_list2matrix(list(x,y, z)))
rbind(m1, m2)
```